# Downloadable files using jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm fairly new to jquery mobile, and am getting an error when trying to link a file in my jquery mobile project for download. I would like a user to be able to download a .zip file from the app, but get either a page loading error, or undefined displayed in a new page. I tried using an anchor tag to link the file to download, but it doesn't seem to work right. I know jquery mobile makes use of the anchor tag, so I don't know if there is something special that needs to be done. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide the code you're working with and what exactly isn't working with that code?

Answer (score 12):

You are likely getting the exception when jQuery Mobile assumes the link is a page and attempts an AJAX page load. Disable AJAX loading on the link.

```
<a href="yourfile.zip" data-ajax="false">Link</a>
```

And I have no idea what the typical mobile browser will do with a link to zip file.

Comment: It worked thanks! Do you know if there is a better method than to zip files for download on mobile devices?

Comment: fwi on android the browser downloads the zip file to the downloads folder. You can find enough unzip apps for android. (I only own android mobile devices) You have to ask yourself why does the user needs this zip on his phone/tablet? I don't know if the zip contains documents, images, videos or even music, but it might be more useful to be able to show/stream the content directly to the users maybe even directly in the browser.

Comment: What should I do if I have a button that generates an excel file? I keep getting a blank page instead of a prompt to download the generated file

Comment: @ShawnSim does the button generate the Excel file or is it a link / url to an endpoint that returns an Excel file? Difficult to know about the specific mobile device but are you disabling AJAX and setting the response / mime type correctly?