# Download file in jQuery mobile project

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

Just started to teach myself javascript and jQuery mobile to create cross platform apps. I want to be able to click on links in my app to download a PDF file from a document that is synchronized (overwrites) with the local (on the phone) version of the file.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794248/downloadable-files-using-jquery-mobile), I found out I should use `data-ajax="false"`, so here is my first attempt:

```
<a href="http://blablabla/download/pdf" data-ajax="false">Download</a>
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens when I click the link after I have built and transferred it to my phone. It works fine in web browser, but not in Phonegap app. Any ideas what could be wrong? And how can I do this in a better way, to achieve exactly what I intend to make it do? If the file is already downloaded, I want the link to say "Open" instead, and have a link to the local version of the file.

Comment: href="..... download/file.pdf" ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire No, it generates a PDF.

Comment: any errors shown on the browser's console?

Comment: No, works fine in webbrowser. Not working when running as a Phonegap app.

Comment: refer these links :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625640/download-images-and-save-locally-on-iphone-phonegap-app
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: Thanks, will look more into them. You should edit the link to Phonegap doc though. They are way too old. This is updated: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

Comment: You say you are transferring the PDF file to your phone, how are you doing that? I would imagine that right now when you click the link it launches the device's default web browser and then the browser handles things from there?

Comment: @MikeDailor No, in app nothing happens. But if I open in web browser it works like normal.

Comment: What type of device are you running this on (android/ios/windows 8.1/?)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android doesn't have a native PDF viewer in its browser, so it doesn't really know what to do with that PDF link, which means you'll need to download it yourself. One solution would be to use Cordova's File and File Transfer plugins. Here's a complete working example from scratch that downloads a PDF that I've parked on a server and allows the user to open it in a reader app, you can test this as follows. Open a command prompt in the directory where you keep your source code and:

1. Create a Cordova project and move into the project directory. At the command prompt, type:

   `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

   `cd hello`
2. In the www directory inside the project directory, replace the entire contents of the www/index.html file with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        
        <a href="#" onclick="downloadPdf();">Download PDF</a>
        
        <script>
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
                alert("Got deviceready");
            }
        
            function downloadPdf() {
                var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                var inputUri = encodeURI("http://nextwavesoftware.com/downloads/helloworld.pdf");
                var outputPath = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "helloworld.pdf";
                // var outputPath = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/helloworld.pdf";
                alert("Starting download to " + outputPath);
                fileTransfer.download(
                      inputUri,
                      outputPath,
                    function (entry) {
                        alert("Download complete: " + entry.fullPath + ", URL=" + entry.toURL());
                        cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                            entry.toURL(), // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
                            'application/pdf',
                            {
                                error: function (e) {
                                    alert('fileOpener2 error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                                },
                                success: function () {
                                    alert('fileOpener2 file opened successfully');
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        alert("download error: source=" + error.source + ", target=" + error.target + ", error code=" + error.code);
                    });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

3. In the project directory, at the command prompt, type `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer` to add the File Transfer plugin.
4. In the project directory, at the command prompt, type `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file` to add the File plugin.
5. In the project directory, at the command prompt, type `cordova plugin add https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2` to add the File Opener plugin.
6. In the project directory, at the command prompt, type `cordova run android` to build and deploy the app to the emulator or your device.
7. In the emulator or on the device, wait until you see the `Got deviceready` alert and dismiss it; the plugins are now available for use.
8. In the emulator or on the device, click the `Download PDF` button.

You should see a "Download complete" dialog. Dismiss the dialog, and you should get another asking you to select the app to use to open the PDF file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long and informative answer. It seems to work, but unfortunately I am not able to find helloworld.pdf on my found even though it said "Download complete: /helloworld.pdf". I guess something may be wrong with the save directory or so. Any ideas how I can save it in ie. my app folder or make this work?

Comment: The best way to work with the file system cross-platform is through the Cordova File plugin which we installed & used to create the output path in this example. Have a look at the docs here: http://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file. At this point you've already downloaded the file and stored it in a folder where you can get to it, now you can access it via it's URL (entry.nativeURL in the above example) or its path (entry.fullPath).

Comment: To follow up on my previous comment (since it appears I can't edit it): the URL of the file in this case (retrieved via `entry.nativeURL()`)  would be "file:///data/data/com.example.hello/files/helloworld.pdf". But, as the Android webview doesn't have native PDF support,you *still* can't just put a `<a href="file:///data/data/com.example.hello/files/helloworld.pdf">Open PDF</a>` on your page since the webview still doesn't know how to handle it; nothing will happen when you click it. To open it, you will need another plugin like FileOpener2: https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

Comment: Thanks a lot for following this up. The strange thing is that I recieve no errors, until I want to open the PDF, then it won't find it. And I am not able to find helloworld.pdf in file manager either.

Comment: I just found out I am not supposed to find the file as it is hidden in my file manager. I tried using FileOpener2, and used `cordova.file.dataDirectory + "helloworld.pdf"` for path. I received the error "Cannot open PDF". Even though I am able to do it if I download it directly from the web.

Comment: Hmmm yeah, same result here; FileOpener2 passes the file name to the PDF reader, and then the reader says "Can't open the file". I've updated the code & added the FileOpener2 stuff, can you try it on your device and verify that verify that it behaves the same way for you?

Comment: Yes, exactly same problem here. Seems like the PDF viewer aren't able to read the hidden folder?

Comment: Ok, figured it out; other apps can't access the cordova.file.dataDirectory, so we need to use cordova.file.externalDataDirectory instead. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, it works at my hand as well now. Thanks a lot for your effort. You answer really stands out. As far as I know this will only be working on Android though, so for the iOS version I guess I'll just need to change the path.